# Apos mudar o nome de um campo em uma tabela, como fazer para atualizar todo o projeto Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usei o Scaffold para gerar um pequeno projeto, depois mudei o nome de um campo em uma tabela, (algo que é raro mas, acontece na vida real), como fazer para atualizar todo o projeto?
P.S.: Já foi feito sem erro o rake db:migrate e a tabela já está com o nome do campo alterado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer dizer por "atualizar todo o projeto" ? Gerar novamente o Scaffold pra ele?

```
rails g scaffold <model>
```

Terá que sobrescrever os arquivos já gerados.

Caso você tenha feito alterações importantes nos arquivos gerados eu aconselho fortemente que tu faça a edição manual (adicione o campo às views, controllers, etc.).

Não esqueça que se você não utilizou o migration para criar essa alteração, apenas alterar o arquivo principal de migração não reflete no db:migrate. Nesse caso, tu teria que dropar o banco (db:drop), cria-lo novamente (db:create) e, aí sim, migrar (db:migrate). Só CUIDADO com esses passos pois apagará tudo que você já tem de registro, portanto, para migrações sempre use o comando:

```
rails g migration <acao>
```

Links relacionados:

1. [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)